# Executing a list of commands on command prompt from within my VB.NET Application

Tags: vb.net, windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to achieve the following from the application that I am developing.

On click of a button a folder is created in a specific location, (Set in the GUI.) I need this folder to be hidden such that even if the user clicks the "View hidden items" Option, they will not be able to see this folder. I have tried doing this:

```
            Dim di As DirectoryInfo

        di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path) 'path is a variable with the location

        di.Attributes = FileAttributes.System
        di.Attributes = FileAttributes.Hidden
```

This however does not work. As an alternative, I created the folder using the application and executed the following code in cmd prompt:

```
attrib +s +h D:\Documents\FolderName
```

This works, i.e. it hides the folder even when view hidden items is checked.

What I want to know is, how can I open up cmd prompt from within my application, for argument sake, when the create folder button is clicked, and execute this code in command prompt? I tried using the

`process.start("cmd.exe", "attrib +s +h D:\Documents\FolderName")`

but this does not work. It just opens cmd prompt with the directory set as my applications debug folder.

My question is, how can I execute my command line statements from within my VB.NET application and after executing the statements, close cmd prompt? I thought of adding a new "Console Application" project to my solution but I have no experience working with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You are assigning two times the attributes, first you assign the system attribute, second you replace the system attribute to hidden attribute. Keep in mind that the property replaces the existing attributes, not adds or removes, so use it properlly.

Comment: Also, the CMD expects a switch (/C | /K) to specify the command arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to execute `attrib` (what, by the way, can be done by relying on the `Process` class), just to use the `Attributes` property right. Sample code:

```
Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Path)
di.Create()
di.Attributes = FileAttributes.System Or FileAttributes.Hidden
```